# Why does D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromMemory only upload a partial copy of my texture?

Tags: directx-11

I have a problem with the D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromMemory helper function.

I read some texture from a file or ZIP and pass the raw bytes and length to the helper function, however only part of the texture is uploaded (as confirmed by PIX).
I tried fiddling with the length manually but to no avail.
Here is the code that loads the texture from file:

```
struct FileDataLoader
{
    void Load()
    {
        std::ifstream file(mFileName);

        if (file)
        {
            file.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
            std::streampos length = file.tellg();
            file.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);

            mBuffer.resize(length);
            file.read(&mBuffer[0],length);
            file.close();
        }
    }

    void Decompress(void*& data, std::size_t& numBytes)
    {
        data = &mBuffer[0];
        numBytes = mBuffer.size();
    }

    std::wstring mFileName;
    std::vector<char> mBuffer;
};

FileDataLoader fdl;
fdl.mFileName = L"Content\\Textures\\Smoke.dds";
fdl.Load();
void* bytes;
std::size_t size;
fdl.Decompress(bytes, size);
DXCall(D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromMemory(device, bytes, size, NULL, NULL, &particleTexture, NULL));
```

That is only a sample code that I am using to debug this problem, and I narrowed it down to the file loading and the D3DX helper function.
Now if I do this instead:

```
DXCall(D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileW(device, L"Content\\Textures\\Smoke.dds", NULL, NULL, &particleTexture, NULL));
```

it works perfectly fine.

Any idea on why it would not upload the texture entirely ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When opening the file, you need to specify that the file is binary:

```
std::ifstream file( fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary );
```

Without the `std::ios::binary` flag you're reading in plain text by default, which is not what D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromMemory expects.

Comment: Hmmm that is an _old_ issue, I've since moved to a different library to load texture BUT, you do have a very valid point and that might have been my problem. (would have been hard to pin-point with tired eyes hehe)
So I'll accept your answer, thank you kindly !